# pro tools swapping shortcut keys around!

Tags: pro-tools, troubleshooting, pt-quick-keys

I keep having this annoying Pro Tools bug; the next start end key (") keeps swapping shortcuts with the tab key, so instead of heading to the next region when I hit it, it changes the edit mode! Driving me crackers. Could also end up being deadly if I knock into shuffle mode and accidently pull my edits out of sync. Any ideas on how to correct this? it goes on restart, but thats a pain. Pro Tools HD 8.4 on a PC if you need to know....

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I've never had this problem. Have you tried a different keyboard? Sounds like something mechanically wrong if one key suddenly does another function. Possibly look on the DUC if anyone has had a similar problem?

If worse comes to worse and you still need to work today, a quick fix to this would be to put yourself into Shuffle Lock mode - that ensures you never go into Shuffle by accident.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check which language your OS has your keyboard set to.  There are slight differences between the three Englishes (US, British, Canadian), though I'm not exactly sure what they are.